# OpenCV Resize changes values

Tags: c++, opencv, resize

maybe this is very simple, but somehow I can't figure out what's wrong.
I have a single columns cv::Mat which I wish to resize to a square matrix.
This is the code:

```
int matSize = 5;
Mat src(matSize, 1, CV_8UC1);
//Fill src with data...(all ones but one zero)
cout << "src:\n" << src << endl;

Mat output(matSize, matSize, CV_8UC1);
resize(src.t(), output, output.size());
cout << "output:\n"output << endl;
```

The output looks like this:

```
src:
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
output:
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1;
1, 1, 1, 1, 1;
1, 1, 1, 1, 1;
1, 1, 1, 1, 1;
1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

So the zero gets lost! I need this in a bigger context, but wish to get it to work in a small scale first.
Please help!

Comment: Oh I am so sorry. It was reshape, not resize! The zero got lost because of interpolation!With reshape it works fine.

Comment: Either delete your question or add an answer to it (you currently answered in the "comments" section).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself, the right function is "reshape" instead of "resize" which is used to "scale" a matrix, instead of changing its header to get different access to its data.